# An explanation for Barendregt use of Y combinator in an equation

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I am going through the following lecture notes on lambda calculus by Barendregt and Barendsen :

http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf

Here at page 12 , after introducing fixed point theorem a small exercise which is an attempt to prove the following has been posted :
$ \exists G  \forall X $ $GX =SGX $.

It first proceeds to  the implication

$Gx$ = $SGx$

which implies :
$G$ = $ \lambda x .SGx $

which implies :
$G $ = $ (\lambda gx.Sgx)G$

and then it concludes that :

$G$ = $Y$ $( \lambda g x.Sgx)$ where $Y $ is the fixed point combinator .

I am unable to figure out how was G found out to be  $Y$ $( \lambda g x.Sgx)$ in the last step ? How was this conclusion reached up to ?

Comment: Y satisfies the equation $Y f = f (Y f)$ for all $f$, and so $g=Yf$ solves $g = fg$ for all $f$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : And f here would be $(  \lambda gx.Sgx) $ ?

Comment: Right, pattern matching would suggest that.

Comment: The direction of implication is wrong: taking $G=YF$ implies $G=FG$, not the other way around. So, taking $G=Y\ldots$ is only one way to solve the requirement on $G$ (other solutions exist), but that's enough for the goal. All your uses of "implies" should instead be "is implied by".

Comment: @Chi :  Yes , sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The Y combinator satisfies the equation $Y f = f(Y f)$. Hence $g = Yf$ solves the equation $g = f g$. In your case, the function $f$ is $\lambda g x.Sgx$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
& G=Y(\lambda gx.Sgx) & (*)\\
& G=(\lambda gx.Sgx) Y (\lambda gx.Sgx) & \text{(by FPT (ii))} \\
& G=(\lambda gx.Sgx)G & \text{(by *)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $G=Y(\lambda gx.Sgx) \implies G=(\lambda gx.Sgx)G$